# Area commanded from given point

Tags: raster, point, area, contour

I want to define the area below a contour that slopes at a particular angle (say -0.05%) from a particular point, for many points.

I have a DEM, and can compute contours at a particular level (say 200 meters), and a grid/raster of slopes.

But I don't see how to compute the a "contour" with a particular slope (-0.05%) from a point.
[image]

I will use the contour to intersect with a polygon layer (administrative areas for example) to compute the areas of administrative areas that are below or above the sloping contour.

I prefer to use ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, but could work in R or QGIS (at a push).

Comment: Actually I want the "contour" from a point with a slope away from the point of, say, -0.05% - 5cm per 100m. Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit your original post to rephrase it to include your updated question.

Comment: Do you have a DEM available instead of contour lines? Then you could use the Slope tool to create a slope raster, and reclassify either based on a certain elevation and/or slope.

Comment: Please, choose a software firstly, otherwise your question will become too vast

Comment: Thanks for coments. THe question has been edited (@ycartwhelen) . I don't understand how reclassification of slopes (both of which I can do) would enable me to identify the 0.05% fall "sloping contour" polyline that originates from my point(s) that I want to intersect with a polygon layer (also @ycartwhelen). I need to identify and connect points on the surface that have this relation first to the point, and then successively to each other until they reach the edge of the DEM. Thanks again for ideas and suggestions. Lets say I use ArcMap (10.8.1), but the others mentioned also a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you haven't already, use your DEM to create a slope layer using the [Slope](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/slope.htm) tool.
2. [Reclassify](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) your slope raster to create a binary raster (1s and 0s/NoData) of "desirable" slopes and "undesirable" slopes. For example < 0.05% and > 0.05%, or anything between 0.045% and 0.055% is desirable and all other slopes are undesirable.
3. [Polygonize](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm) the binary raster so you end up with polygons of your desirable slopes. Your choice as to whether or not you simplify the edges, but I would probably recommend this.
4. [Spatially join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) your starting points with the desirable slope polygons (points as target features, polygons as join features) to associate each point with the area around it at the desirable slope. Pay attention to settings, as it is possible that some points will not be in an area of desired slope, and some desirable slope areas may not have any points in them.
   4b. If your points aren't already associated with the administrative boundaries you might want to spatially join them too.
5. [Intersect](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) your slope areas associated with points with your administrative boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ycartwhelen. This is what I understood you to suggest, and I could not see how step 2 solves my problem. Few pixels have a slope of less that 0.05%. I have probably not been very clear. I'll try again. What I need are "contour" lines with a slopes of -0.05% from my point of interest rather than horizontal contour lines (at a constant elevation). The idea is that -0.05% is roughly the minimum slope required for water to flow downhill. I want to trace the area "commanded" by a canal that ran along such a sloping contour (both sides of the slope from the point).

Comment: So maybe iterate through your points (really through the slopes of your points), and reclassify the raster each time instead based on slope_at_point +/- 0.05?

Comment: this gave me an idea (https://gismapdesign.com/calculating-slope-from-contours-using-buffers-and-creating-a-slope-map/). Suppose I want to find the point on a contour 1 meter below my point. Buffer my point by 2000 meters and intersect with this contour. That gives me the points on the -1 m contour that are -.05% from my point. repeat from these points. But how to automate it (python beginner)? I'm puzzled how contouring routimes seem to work quite rapidly! Maybe this could work with pixels from the DEM (I'm also raster naive)?

Comment: When you say the "area commanded by the canal" do you mean its watershed? Or rather, the "watershed" right along the main part of the canal as opposed to a main source of water far upstream. If so, go look at the Hydrology toolbox. You might also want to edit your original question to include a drawing/diagram of what you are trying to find, because I'm still pretty confused.

Comment: I've modified the question and added a graphic.